# Data expansion R/Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

I have a large csv file recorded as below,

```
name         year         value
brand1       2000         45,000
brand2       2000         42,000
brand3       2000         46,000

brand1       2001         41,600
brand2       2001         49,000
brand4       2001         47,000

brand1       2002         39,000
brand5       2002         40,500
brand3       2002         42,800
```

I would like to turn my large csv as below, such that all unique names that span all the years recorded are captured and their value equated to zero where the names miss in a specific year of recording. See this,

```
name       year      value
brand1       2000         45,000
brand2       2000         42,000
brand3       2000         46,000
brand4       2000         0000
brand5       2000         0000

brand1       2001         41,600
brand2       2001         49,000
brand4       2001         47,000
brand3       2001         0000
brand5       2001         0000

brand1       2002         39,000
brand5       2002         40,500
brand3       2002         42,800
brand2       2002         0000
brand4       2000         0000
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Questions not focused on a single programming language and with no code attempt are normally closed.  Best way to keep it alive would be to decide on which language you want and show your best attempt in that language.

Comment: Simply left join merge a dataset of all possible combinations of *name* and *year*. Then convert NAs to zeros.

Comment: _Thoughts?_ What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution in R.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(name = c("brand1", "brand2", "brand4", "brand5", "brand1"), 
                 year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001),
                 value = c(53, 32, 242, 43, 23))


df1 <- df %>% complete(year, name, fill = list(value = 0))
```